# Docker-compose: Start container after another with timeout

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to start `myapp-1` with `myapp-2`, then sleep for 30 seconds and only then start `myapp-3`?

Tried this `docker-compose.yml` with no luck.

```
version: '3'
services:
  myapp-1:
    container_name: myapp-1
    image: myapp:latest
    restart: always
  myapp-2:
    container_name: myapp-2
    image: myapp:latest
    restart: always
  test-sleep:
    image: busybox
    command: ["/bin/sleep", "30"]
    depends_on:
      - "myapp-1"
      - "myapp-2"
  myapp-3:
    container_name: myapp-3
    image: myapp:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - "test-sleep"
```

Comment: You can't directly do this in Compose; is there a specific reason you want to?  (You can't wait for a container to exit, or wait for it to be "really running".)  [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y) discusses the broader problem of waiting for a dependent container to be ready.

Comment: **See Also**: [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31746182/1366033)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `docker-compose.yml` you proposed could not address your use case, as the `depends_on` property does not wait for the dependencies to be ready (or terminated), but only for them to be started (i.e., in your example, `myapp-3` is started as soon as the `/bin/sleep 30` command has been *started*).

See e.g. the corresponding [doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on):

> `depends_on` does not wait for [dependencies] to be “ready” before starting [the service] - only until they have been started. If you need to wait for a service to be ready, see [Controlling startup order](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) for more on this problem and strategies for solving it.

The link above mentions several tools (including [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it)) that could be used to wait that some service dependencies are ready (provided they expose a web service at a given TCP port).

Otherwise, if you just want to wait for 30s before starting `myapp-3`, assuming the `Dockerfile` of `myapp-3` contains `CMD ["/prog", "first argument"]`, you could just get rid of `test-sleep` and write something like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  myapp-1:
    container_name: myapp-1
    image: myapp:latest
    restart: always
  myapp-2:
    container_name: myapp-2
    image: myapp:latest
    restart: always
  myapp-3:
    container_name: myapp-3
    image: myapp:latest
    restart: always
    command:
      - '/bin/sh'
      - '-c'
      - '/bin/sleep 30 && /prog "first argument"'
    depends_on:
      - "myapp-1"
      - "myapp-2"
```